# SpaServices expected behaviour without Node installed

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have a couple of ASP.NET Core / Angular web applications that have been developed using JavascriptServices.

They both use server-side prerendering, as per the default behaviour in the angular template.

When I deploy them to a test server that does not have Node.js installed, one of them gives a runtime error on the server complaining that it cannot find Node.exe, but the other one loads the angular application successfully.

The one that work uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 1.1.2.
The one that does not work uses Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.1.

I can't work out why one of the works. Did the old version of SpaServices gracefully fall back on not doing server-side prerendering when it cannot find Node.exe?

What is the expected behaviour in that scenario?

Comment: i believe node.js is required for ssr, it is weird for me you were able to make one of your project run without it.

Comment: I know it's a stupid question, since you have said that one of the servers doesn't have node installed, but what happens if you issue the following command on both machines: `node --version`?

Comment: @JamieTaylor They were actually both running on the same server. It couldn't find node from the command line, and I even searched the disk for a node executable in case there was one in an unexpected location.

My only other guess is that the one that worked was somehow mis-configured so it didn't even try server-side prerendering.

Comment: @Ergwun Server side pre-rendering is done at compile time for release mode, I believe. Are they both sent to the server as a release build?

Comment: @JamieTaylor Hmmm...I did switch to developer mode to see what the actual error was for the one that didn't work. I'll do some more testing - thanks.